# Linear Discriminant Analysis

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, scikits

I am using sklearn.lda for a classification purpose and was a little puzzled about the score function that prints the mean classification error.
Is it determined by leave one out - jackknife?
How do I interpret the result? It's only a float value without much documentation.

Thanks in advance,
EL

Answer (score 1):

The `score` method takes samples `X` and their true labels `y` and compares its own predictions with `y`. It returns the mean accuracy, which is always a single figure. For example,

```
lda = LDA().fit(X, y)
print(lda.score(X, y))
```

will print the accuracy of the classifier on its own training set.

Every classifier has a `score` method, which usually (though not necessarily) returns mean accuracy. The method is used by the `GridSearchCV` model selection algorithm to determine the quality of the classifier if you don't explicitly give it a `scoring` argument.

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer! My question now is: how do I interpret the output value? I just got 0.8 on a test set. Thanks for the classname anyway, makes me understand scikit little better.

Comment: @ElDude: that means you have 80% accuracy on your test set. Whether that's good depends on the problem.

Comment: cool. Thanks. One last question: which method provides the parameters of the discriminant function? get_params gives me this:{'priors': None, 'n_components': None}

Comment: @ElDude: there's no such method, scikit-learn stores model parameters as public attributes. Check the docstring, `help(LDA)`, under Attributes.